# how to get the button enabled once you keep the cursor in the textbox in C#?

Tags: c#

I wanted to know how to disable a button which should only be enabled when the cursor is kept on the textbox or when we are going to type in that textbox . Need it in C#.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Post your best try and people will help you with the details. This is not a "code-it-for-me" service.

Comment: Use the mouse-hover and focus-enter event.

Comment: _Disable a button which should only be enabled_? When do you want it to get disabled exactly?

Comment: it should be disabled at first and enable when the cursor is kept on the textbox ie, when we are going to type something in the textbox.

Comment: What if you set the focus on textbox and them enter no text. Then the button will be enabled with no text in textbox

Comment: Is this on a web page, a winforms application, or something else? (Which event handlers you can use may vary depending on this)

Answer (score 1):

GotFocus, LostFocus event may help you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.GotFocus += textBox1_GotFocus;
        textBox1.LostFocus += textBox1_LostFocus;
    }

    void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot..bt i am not getting the gotfocus and lostfocus property. any namespace to be included to get that?

Comment: You never can never click on the button with this code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use text box Enter event like the below

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to be enabled only when there's some text in the textbox do this. Otherwise it makes no scenes to disabled your button.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: tried this. but it is not working for me. when i put breakpoint on this code also its not going there.

Comment: You mean when you change the text in textBox1, `textBox1_TextChanged` event doesn't get fired? In this case somthing's wrong in your UI desiging